# How do I write debug info in a C# page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Note: This problem was occurring because the render event was being overridden for the page, which in turn caused the .net error display that would have been visible to instead display garbage, and the coding error in the class was not seen.

---

I want to place debug info a C# web page. I made a static class containing an array and debug messages are added at various places in code. The class has a get method returning a string having all array elements concatenated. At the bottom of the page I have :

```
      </body>
    <!--debug=<%=debugging.get()%> -->
    </html>
```

This always screws up the page. The entire page displays garbage. If I use a text constant such as the following it works OK:

```
      </body>
    <!--debug=<%="xxx"%> -->
    </html>
```

I'm thinking it may be a unicode issue or something. I've tried conversions and can't get it to work. The class is:

```
using System;

public static class debugging {
  public static String[] messages;

  public static void add(String v) {
    Array.Resize(ref messages, messages.Length + 1);
    messages[messages.Length - 1] = v;
  }

  public static String get() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++) s += messages[i] + "\r\n";
    return s;
  }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: If I use any code at all between <% and %>, such as dropping into code, and using response.write, the page always displays trash. Using constants is OK, but no variables. I was able to display a connection string, though.

Comment: I tried using lower case string instead of String in the class. Info for .ConnectionStrings[zz].ConnectionString says a lower case string is returned. No difference. I can use <%= .ConnectionString %> though.

Comment: You should never place your class inside the `System` namespace. Use your own namespace. Common formats include `MyCompany.MyProject`, `MyProject`, and `MyCompany.MyProject.MySubproject`.

Comment: can you please show what exactly are printed ? what are this garbage ?

Comment: The page looks like inappropriately rendered unicode. It's as if putting a string variable into the page coerces the stream into unicode rather than ansi-7 bit. It seems like a bug in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class is buggy, and probably that's why you get the garbage as you say. Your `message` parameter throw exception as it is. Here is a working class.

```
public static class debugging
{
    public static String[] messages = null;

    public static void add(String v)
    {
        if (messages == null)
            messages = new string[1];
        else
            Array.Resize(ref messages, messages.Length + 1);

        messages[messages.Length - 1] = v;
    }

    public static String get()
    {
        if (messages == null) 
           return string.Empty;
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++) s += messages[i] + "\r\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```

and here is an improvement version of that class

```
public static class debugging
{
    public static List<string> cMsg = new List<string>();

    public static void add(String v)
    {
        cMsg.Add(v);
    }

    public static String get()
    {
        StringBuilder sbOnMe = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var One in cMsg)
            sbOnMe.AppendLine(One);

        return sbOnMe.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the class. It is a simple class for a reason. The problem happens on the page for any type of variable used, whether or not the class is even used.

Comment: @subjectivist But I make a page locally and test it, its now working as you have it - its throw errors - and then I make that and test it and works find, the page is not break.

Comment: @subjectivist Its not simple, its buggy and complicate. The one I make is simple.

Comment: @subjectivist Show me what is the garbage that you say that you have to see ? its probably the error thrown by that class... oh I wast my time...

Comment: The render method is being overridden on the page, doing compression and other stuff. Because of this the .net error page was being corrupted and not rendering properly. Because I could not see the error page I did not see the class indeed had an error, and did not know what the app was doing. When I disabled the override method for the page, the .net error page was then visible, and I could see the error in the class. Thanks for helping me with this!

Answer (score 0):

The returning text is probably messing up with the html or comment markup.

Maybe you can try something like

`<div style="display:none;"><%=debugging.get()%></div>`

Edit:

You can also try HTMLEncode that might do the trick.

`<%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(debugging.get())%>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe putting the output on a PRE tag instead of an HMTL comment?

```
</body>
<pre style="display:none;">debug=<%=HtmlUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval(debugging.get())) %></pre>
</html>
```

MAYBE it will work this way.

Comment: This does not work either. Any reference to a variable or function causes the page to display garbage.